# AttributeError: Excel.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone When Refreshing Excel

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to automate excel refreshable reports and I keep getting
AttributeError: Excel.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone.

My goal is to have python open the excel report, refresh it twice, then save it with a new name.
It was working a few weeks ago, but IT did some updates and now I get this error.
I am running it using anaconda, with an environment that I created.

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 64-bit 
Python: 3.11 64 bit

The error is causing the excel file 'report_pathway' to stay open.
However, even after running taskkill /IM Excel.exe /F I still get the error.

```
# This is my code.

import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime

report_pathway = '//WorkReportPathway'

# Start an instance of Excel
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open(report_pathway)

# Refresh all data connections twice to make sure pivot tables update as well.
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

# Save Report
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Save()
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True

# Quit
xlapp.Quit()

with open(report_pathway+".xlsx", "rb") as f1:
  with open(report_pathway+ "_"+ timeline()+".xlsx", "wb") as f2:
    f2.write(f1.read())



# This is the error
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
WorkReportPathway\Report.ipynb Cell 2 line 1
 13 # Refresh all data connections twice to make sure pivot tables update as well.
 14 wb.RefreshAll()
---> 15 xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
 16 wb.RefreshAll()
 17 xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

 File c:\Users\brycec\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\swnenv\Lib\site-        packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py:638, in CDispatch.__getattr__(self, attr)
635     return self._get_good_object_(ret)
637 # no where else to look.
--> 638 raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))

AttributeError: Excel.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

Comment: I'm never quite sure what `DispatchEx()` does: I usually just use `Dispatch()`, or `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()`.  Maybe try the latter and see if it helps. Fwiw, I'm on Excel 2302 (Build 16130.20306) and `win32com` finds the `CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()` method OK. I suppose it is possible that the Type Library has changed, but that would be unusual. Maybe check in your python site-packages under `gen_py/3.11/` and delete any folders. It might be you have a cached COM wrapper that no longer matches the Type Library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
A sleep(10) did it for me

```
workbook.RefreshAll()
time.sleep(10)
xl.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
```

Didn't test the time, maybe shorter is also possible